# How to build Android L app to support lower sdk version devices? [Eclipse]

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been trying to test my app it works which works fine with 4.4.4 and lower, but when I try to compile it with `targetSdkVersion 'L'`, I am unable to run it on lower version, is there a work around to do achieve this on Eclipse. I am unable to copmile for lower sdk version of Android if I set the `targetSdkVersion` to `'L'`. I have seen some work around using Android Studio but I still don't feel comfortable with the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L is a preview release of the SDK, and you can't use it to build apps that will run on previous, released versions of the Android platform. It's intended for testing your code against the L APIs and L emulator, not for building shipping apps. If you want to run on non-L devices, use a released version of the SDK (API 19 or 20).